# How do I retrieve data from a class in a span?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to retrieve some portion of data from HTML code. Here it is :

```
<span
class="Z3988" style="display:none;"
title="ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&amp;rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Ajournal&amp;
rfr_id=info%3Asid%2Focoins.info%3Agenerator&amp;rft.genre=article&amp;
rft.atitle=Parliamentarism Rationalized&amp;
rft.title=East European Constitutional Review&amp;
rft.stitle=E. Eur. Const. Rev.&amp;rft.date=1993&amp;
rft.volume=2&amp;rft.spage=33&amp;rft.au=Tanchev, Evgeni&amp;
rft_id=http://heinonline.org/HOL/Page?handle%3Dhein.journals/eeurcr2%26id%3D33%26div%3D%26collection%3D">
</span>
```

I tried to use e.g.:

`document.querySelector("span.Z3988").textContent`

`document.getElementsbyClassName("Z3988")[0].textContent`

My final aim is to get what comes after:

1. rft.atitle (`Parliamentarism Rationalized`)
2. rft.title (`East European Constitutional Review`)
3. rft.date
4. rft.volume
5. rft.spage
6. rft.au

How do I do that? I'd like to avoid RegEx.

Comment: All the text in in the title **attribute** of the span.. not actually contained in the span.

Comment: the data you wish to get is the one provided as the title attribute, correct?

Comment: I don't know, because I'm to new to HTML. Here's the link to this page: http://heinonline.org/HOL/LandingPage?handle=hein.journals/eeurcr2&div=11&id=&page=

Comment: Once you have the `title` contents, I really would suggest using regex. Regex is an incredibly useful string-parsing tool; look up a tutorial and get familiar with it.

Comment: I am familiar with RegEx but I thought that there is more `elegant` way.

Comment: The `title` attribute is supposed to be used for tooltips. Why are you putting data in there?

Comment: There is one more "elegant" way and that is with `URLSearchParams` see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41029097/1008999) below

Comment: @Barmar It is not my code.

Comment: Why is there no accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to grab the title attribute:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Z3988")[0].getAttribute("title");
```

Comment: You were first to answer and hence accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Get the title text of span,

Spit it at `=` , join using character that will not appear in the string I prepared `^`, do same for `;`,  and split at unique character used `^` in this case and then pick value at every even index. If you need string just join it.

Example Sinppet:

```js
var spanTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("Z3988")["0"].getAttribute("title");

var data = spanTitle.split("=").join("^").split(";").join("^").split("^")

var finaldata = data.filter(function(d, index) {
  return !!index % 2;
})

console.log(finaldata)
```

```html
<span class="Z3988" style="display:none;" title="ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&amp;rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Ajournal&amp;
rfr_id=info%3Asid%2Focoins.info%3Agenerator&amp;rft.genre=article&amp;
rft.atitle=Parliamentarism Rationalized&amp;
rft.title=East European Constitutional Review&amp;
rft.stitle=E. Eur. Const. Rev.&amp;rft.date=1993&amp;
rft.volume=2&amp;rft.spage=33&amp;rft.au=Tanchev, Evgeni&amp;
rft_id=http://heinonline.org/HOL/Page?handle%3Dhein.journals/eeurcr2%26id%3D33%26div%3D%26collection%3D">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have in your title looks to be a url search query...

```js
var elm = document.querySelector('.Z3988')
var params = new URLSearchParams(elm.title) // parse everything

console.log(...params) // list all
console.log(params.get('rft.title')) // getting one example
```

```html
<span class="Z3988" style="display:none;" title="ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&amp;rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Ajournal&amp;rfr_id=info%3Asid%2Focoins.info%3Agenerator&amp;rft.genre=article&amp;rft.atitle=Parliamentarism Rationalized&amp;rft.title=East European Constitutional Review&amp;rft.stitle=E. Eur. Const. Rev.&amp;rft.date=1993&amp;rft.volume=2&amp;rft.spage=33&amp;rft.au=Tanchev, Evgeni&amp;rft_id=http://heinonline.org/HOL/Page?handle%3Dhein.journals/eeurcr2%26id%3D33%26div%3D%26collection%3D"></span>
```

Comment: There will be browser compatibility issue with `URLSearchParams`, as MDN document says it is not supported in IE and safari. I am working on IE 11 and your snippet thows error `URLSearchParams is undefined`

Comment: @A.J Upgrade to Edge, IE is dead... no more maintenance for IE nowdays

Comment: Well, I have to use IE. The programming language I use doesn't support Edge but it does IE.

Comment: @Endless - Totally agree with you, but most of the corporate users/ customers are still stuck at IE.

Comment: Sucks to be you? :P What programming language are you working in? ActiveX, Silverlight? This is language you are talking about has no cross browser compatibility if it only works in IE - switch to html5!

Comment: Tell your customers to upgrade! :)

Comment: I use AutoHotkey and it only supports IE (by COM).

Answer (score 0):

The way you're outputting content as text is a really bad method. You could try to print each section of your text into element attributes and retrieve each part with element.getAttribute().

Ex:

```
<span id='whatever' stitle='content' spage='content'></span>
```

and retrieve from the selected element.

For the way you have it you might want to try to put that text into a variable and split the values like:

```
var element_text = document.getElementsbyClassName("Z3988")[0].textContent;
var element_specifics = element_text.split(';'); // Separate the text into array splitting by the ';'
```

Comment: doesn't solve the issues - and he can't change his code

Comment: The answer wasn't intended to resolve the problem but to answer with an approach to the solution of his problem. The question and implementation is not very good for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this is going to process down with browser compatibilities or JavaScript versions, but you can definitely sub out the arrow functions for vanilla anonymous functions, and "let" for "var". Otherwise, it fits the parameters of no regex, and even creates a nice way to index for your various keywords.

### My steps:

- Grab the attribute block
- Split it up into array elements containing the desired keywords and contents
- Split up the desired keywords and contents into sub-arrays
- Trim down the contents of each keyword block for symbols and non alphanumerics
- Construct the objects for convenient indexing

Obviously the last portion is just to print out the array of objects in a nice readable format. Hope this helps you out!

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName('Z3988')[0].getAttribute('title')
  let a = x.split('rft.').map((y) => y.split('='))
  a = a.map((x, i) => { 
    x = x.map((y) => {
      let idx = y.indexOf('&')
      return y = (idx > -1) ? y.slice(0, idx) : y
    })    
    let x1 = x[0], x2 = x[1], obj = {}
    obj[x1] = x2
    return a[i] = obj
  })
  a.forEach((x) => {
    let div = document.createElement('div')
    let br = document.createElement('br')
    let text = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(x))
    div.appendChild(text)
    div.appendChild(br)
    document.body.appendChild(div)
  })
}
```

```html
<span
class="Z3988" style="display:none;"
title="ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&amp;rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Ajournal&amp;
rfr_id=info%3Asid%2Focoins.info%3Agenerator&amp;rft.genre=article&amp;
rft.atitle=Parliamentarism Rationalized&amp;
rft.title=East European Constitutional Review&amp;
rft.stitle=E. Eur. Const. Rev.&amp;rft.date=1993&amp;
rft.volume=2&amp;rft.spage=33&amp;rft.au=Tanchev, Evgeni&amp;
rft_id=http://heinonline.org/HOL/Page?handle%3Dhein.journals/eeurcr2%26id%3D33%26div%3D%26collection%3D">
</span>
```